# Database tables relationships i need a few simple examples

Tags: mysql, database

I need two simple examples if its possible.

How should look like a relationship "1x1" between two tables ? 
And how should look like a relationship "1xMany" ?

Comment: 1:1 is rarely needed IMHO, 1:N is abundant, what do you mean exactly with 'how it should look like'?

Comment: Hello & welcome to stackoverflow! We will do what we can to answer your question though I am not sure what you are asking specifically. Please read the help on asking questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    Please state more specifically the problem you are attempting to solve so we can assist you. Here is a resource that you might find valuable if you are just wondering about relationships between tables in databases:http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talk about "1x1" or "1xMany" relationship, we refer to entities which will be finally mapped to tables. But technically speaking, there is not "1x1" or "1xmany" relationship between tables.

Here is a simple example,

You have a department entity (dept_id, dept_name as attributes) and also you have a employee entity (emp_id, first_name, last_name, salary, dept_id).

As you could see, one department can have many employees, so from department to employee there is "1 to Many" relationship. On the other hand, one employee could only belong to one department. So from employee to department there is "1 to 1" relationship.

Hope the explanation will help.